# How to push to multiple remotes?

Tags: git

I had one remote, lets say `origin` and branch `dev`,  pushed all the code.
And added a new remote

```
git remote add newOrigin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

How can i push the same code to the same branch to a new remote?
I tried `git push newOrigin dev`, but git seems just to freeze and do nothing

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that command. You should probably be asked for your github login credentials — is it possible the login prompt was eaten by something and git is waiting for keyboard input?

Comment: @ohlec basically i'm not using github, i use our corporate git server and authenticating by ssh keys

Comment: Have you tried to ssh to that server? Use the same ssh key that is used by git.

Comment: @MarcinPietraszek yes

Comment: Do you get more output when running git push with `-v`?